# Yii accessing relational data via find

Tags: php, yii

I have hasMany defined in model for this find function below.

```
$model=Investor::model()->find('fname=? AND lname=?', array($fname, $lname)
```

Is there a way we can access the relational data in the view?

Comment: how do you typically access data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are two ways:

- Lazy loading.
- Eager loading.

To access via lazy loading (additional SQL queries) you shouldn't add anything to your `find` and in the view you'll just use:

```
<?php foreach($model->relationName as $relatedModel):?>
  // something
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Eager loading will get everything in a single SQL query so it's more efficient in most cases. View will stay the same. The part that's different is `Investor::model()->with('relationName')->find(…`.